Bounds on the Eigenvalues of Perturbations of a Symmetric Matrix
Let us fix $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$ and $\beta\in\mathbb R$. Consider the $2 n\times 2n$ symmetric tridiagonal probability  matrix
$$Q_n :=\begin{bmatrix}
1-\frac{ε}{2} & \frac{ε}{2} & & &  &\\
\frac{ε}{2} & 1-ε & \frac{ε}{2} &  &  & \\
 & \frac{ε}{2} & 1-ε & \frac{ε}{2} &  &  \\
 &  &  & \ddots &  & \\
 &  &  & \frac{ε}{2} & 1-ε & \frac{ε}{2} \\
 &  &  &  & \frac{ε}{2} & 1-\frac{ε}{2} 
\end{bmatrix}$$
and the unitary diagonal matrix
$$D_{n}= \mathrm{Diag}\left(e^{i\beta/n^2},\ldots, e^{i\beta/n^2}, e^{-i\beta/n^2},\ldots, e^{-i \beta/n^2}\right),$$
i.e. $$[D_{n}]_{i,j} =\begin{cases}
e^{i\beta/n^2};& \ \text{if }1\leq i=j\leq n;\\
e^{-i\beta/n^2};& \ \text{if }n+1\leq i=j\leq 2n;\\
0;& \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases} $$

Question: Is it true that there exist a constant $C>0$ and a natural number $N_0$ such for every $n> N_0$, the matrix $\widetilde{Q}_{n}:=D_{n}Q_n$ admits an eigenvalue $\lambda_n$ such that
$$|\lambda_n - 1|\leq \frac{C}{n^2}\quad ? $$

I believe that this should be a consequence of the Bauer-Fike theorem. Which states (in the notation above) that if $\widetilde{Q}_n = V_n \Lambda_n  V_n^{-1}$ (for some diagonal matrix $\Lambda$), then
$$ |1-\lambda_n| \leq \|V_n^{-1}\|\cdot \|V_n\| \cdot \|(\mathrm{Id}_n - D_n) Q_n \|,$$
however, I cannot estimate $\|V_n^{-1}\|$.
Does anyone have a good idea of how to establish such control on the eigenvalues of $\widetilde{Q}_n$:
As a (maybe useful) comment, the eigenvalues of $Q_ε$ can be explicitly computed and are equal to
$$μ_{k,n} = 1 -ε + ε\cos\left(\frac{\pi (k-1) }{2 n} \right),\ \text{for }k\in\{1,\ldots,2n\} $$

Some Comments:
Defining:

$E_n := (D_n - \mathrm{Id})Q_n$,
$X_n := \frac{E_n + E_n^*}{2}$ and $Y_n := \frac{E_n - E_n^*}{2i}$,
$\lambda_{j,n}$ for $j \in \{1, \ldots, 2n\}$ as the eigenvalues of $\widetilde{Q}_n$, such that
$$\mathrm{Re} \lambda_{1,n} \geq \mathrm{Re} \lambda_{2,n} \geq \ldots \geq \mathrm{Re} \lambda_{2n,n}.$$

A result from Kahan, when applied to this context, shows that
$$ \max_j \left| \mathrm{Re} (\lambda_{j,n}) - \mu_{j,n} \right| \leq \|X_n\|_{\mathrm{op}} + \|Y_n\|_{\mathrm{op}} (\log_2 n + 0.4) \leq K \frac{\log_2 n}{n^2} $$
and
$$ \max_j \left| \mathrm{Im} (\lambda_{j,n}) \right| \leq \|Y_n\| \leq K \frac{1}{n^2}, $$
for some constant $K > 0$, where $\|\cdot\|_{\mathrm{op}}$ denotes the operator norm with respect to the 2-Euclidean norm.
Moreover, Kahan also shows that
$$ \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{2n} \left| \mathrm{Re} (\lambda_{j,n}) - \mu_{j,n} \right|^2} \leq \sqrt{2} \|E_n\|_{\mathrm{F}} \leq K \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2}, $$
where $\|\cdot\|_{\mathrm{F}}$ denotes the Frobenius norm.
An additional, maybe useful, observation is that if $\lambda \in \sigma(\widetilde{Q}_n)$, then $\overline{\lambda} \in \sigma(\widetilde{Q}_n)$, i.e. there is a symmetry over the real axis in the eigenvalues of $\widetilde{Q}_n$. Indeed, if $v \in \mathbb{C}^{2n}$ satisfies $\widetilde{Q}_n v = \lambda v$, then it is straightforward to verify that
$$ \widetilde{Q}_n R(\overline{v}) = \overline{\lambda} R(\overline{v}), $$
where
$$ R(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_{2n-1}, v_{2n}) = (v_{2n}, v_{2n-1}, \ldots, v_2, v_1). $$
However, I have not been able to use the above information to solve my problem.

the important thing here is that the condition number of $V$ stays bounded. You could try to prove that the $V_n$ that diagonalizes $\tilde Q_n$ converge to a fixed invertible matrix, so that its condition number also converges
